# How to allow a process to use more memory

Tags: games, steam, ram, memory-usage

I am trying to run a game on Steam at a decent speed. I exceed the system requirements for this game, and the game is already set to minimum graphics, but it is still running slow.

I have been using free and sysinfo to monitor memory usage and when playing a game I still have over 60% free memory. What I want is to be able to use that memory to run the game.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What I will suggest here is, try killing the other unnecessary processes when you run the game. Then there would be more memory available for all the remaining processes, and therefore the performance will increase. In fact it should increase then.

Comment: I've killed all other processes except for the game and sysinfo. It still says I have  more than 60% of memory free, and the game still runs slowly.

Is there any way to allow steam or the game to use more memory or something?

Also thanks for the response.

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718148/how-to-allocate-more-memory-to-a-process-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just tell an application to use more memory; it will only request and use as much memory as it has been programmed to do so.  If the application itself doesn't let you increase the memory in its own configuration then there is no way to force it to do so.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I figured out that it was more an issue of not having enough free memory because a big chunk of memory was cached. More than I needed to be. I cleaned that out and it worked much better and used more memory.